# How do I solve for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop

I have a list with links 'elanlar'
and have a csv file with links.
I want to check for every item in the list of 'elanlar':
if any link in the list exists in csv file, print the link.
Thanks all in advance.

```
    elanlar = ['http://example.com/124124', 'http://example.com/523523']
    
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")
    
    for elan in elanlar:
    
        for row in csv_file:
            if len(row) <= 0:
                pass
            elif elan in row:
                print(row[0])
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with your current code.

Comment: Why the nested for loops, though

Comment: Your code prints the first item from the matching row, not the link which matched. Is this a bug, or is your problem description wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An open file is a *stream;* you can read lines as long as there are more lines, but once you reach the end of the file, reading will no longer produce anything. You then have to close and reopen the file, or rewind it to the beginning.

But none of that is necessary here, of course. Just read the file once and check all the terms on every line.

```py
elanlar = ['http://example.com/124124', 'http://example.com/523523']
    
csv_file = csv.reader(open('file.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")
    
for row in csv_file:
    for elan in elanlar:
        if elan in row:
            print(row[0])
            break
```

You could use `any()` and the dangling `open` without a `close` is easy to avoid;

```py
elanlar = ['http://example.com/124124', 'http://example.com/523523']

with open('file.csv', "r"), delimiter=",") as inputfile:
    csv_file = csv.reader(inputfile)
    for row in csv_file:
        if any(elan in row for elan in elanlar):
            print(row[0])
```

Reading a file is *much* slower than comparing a number of strings (even when that number is in the thousands) so you really want to make sure you read the file only once if that's possible.